# Does there exist an analytic function that satisfies these properties?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Does there exist an analytic function $f:\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0<|z|<1\}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to0}[z^{-3}f^2(z)]=1$?

I'm assuming that there is not such a function, so I've been trying to prove this. Assuming that such a function does exist, there have been a few ideas I've tried. The first was the following:

$\displaystyle\lim_{z\to0}[z^{-3}f^2(z)]=1\implies g:\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0<|z|<1\}\to\mathbb{C}$ by $g(z):=z^{-3}f^2(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$, and so $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to0}z^{-2}f^2(z)=0\implies \displaystyle\lim_{z\to0}z^{-1}f(z)=0$, and then I get stuck.

Another attempt was the following (still assuming, in hopes of contradiction, that such a function $f$ exists):

$\displaystyle\lim_{z\to0}[z^{-3}f^2(z)]=1\implies\lim_{z\to0}[(z^{-1}f^{2/3}(z))^3]=1\implies\lim_{z\to0}[z^{-1}f^{2/3}(z)]=$ some cube root of unity. From this, we can get that $f^{2/3}(z)$ as a removable singularity at $z=0$, and so $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to0}f^{2/3}(z)=0$. Now I know that we define $f^{2/3}(z)=\exp[\frac{2}{3}\log[f(z)]]$ (where $\log$ is a branch of the logarithm), but again I get stuck here.

I realize that nowhere in either attempt did I use the fact that $f$ is defined on the punctured disk, and maybe using a power series would be helpful? I don't really know. Any help would be appreciated; this is preparation for a qualifying exam and do not feel confident in my analysis skills at all.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{z\to 0} z^{-1} f(z) = 0$ means that $z{-1} f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $0$, which is a zero. What can you then say about the order of the zero of $f$ in $0$?

Comment: Can I say that the order of the zero of $f$ is then two? I still don't see how this helps, though...

Comment: The order of the zero of $f$ in $0$ is at least two then, so $f(z)^2$ has a zero of order at least four.

Comment: I think I figured it out as I was falling asleep last night. I had figured that $f^2(z)$, then had the zero of order at least four (like you just said). So then we can write $f^2(z)=z^m*g(z)$ where $m\geq4$ and $g(z)$ is analytic on $|z|\leq1$ with $g(z)\neq0$. But then we have $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to0}[z^{-3}f^2(z)]=\lim_{z\to0}z^{m-3}g(z)=0$, contradicting what was assumed. Therefore such a function, $f$ cannot exist.

Comment: Yup. That's correct. Also, if $\lvert z^{-k}f(z)^m\rvert \to 1$ for $z\to 0$, then $\lvert f(z)\rvert \sim \lvert z\rvert^{k/m}$ for $z\to 0$. If $f$ is holomorphic in the punctured disk, then either $f$ has an essential singularity and no asymptotic $\lvert f(z)\rvert \sim C\cdot \lvert z\rvert^\alpha$ holds, or, if the singularity is removable or a pole, the exponent $\alpha$ in $\lvert f(z)\rvert \sim C\cdot\lvert z\rvert^\alpha$ is an integer.

Comment: All right! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the zero of f at $0$ is two, then you can write a Taylor expansion at zero, $$ f= \sum _{n=0}^{\infty} {a_n z^{n+2}}$$ and factor out $z^2$ so that $$f=z^2(a_0+a_1z+...)$$ and thus $$f^2=z^4(a_0+a_1z+...)^2$$ and then the limit divided by $z^3$ cant be one.

Same goes if the order of zero is higher than two.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\lim_{z\to0}[z^{-3}f^2(z)]=1 \implies f(z)=\frac{1}{z^{3/2}}\frac{1+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots}{1+b_1z+b_2z^2+\cdots}$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that such an $f$ exists, and  consider the function
$$g(z):=\left({f(z)\over z}\right)^2\qquad(z\in\dot U)\ ,$$
where $U$ is a sufficiently small disk with center $0\in{\mathbb C}$.
Since $\lim_{z\to0}{g(z)\over z}=1$ it follows that $g$ is in fact analytic in all of $U$, and that there is an analytic function $h:\ U\to{\mathbb C}$ with $$g(z)=z\>h(z)\quad(z\in U),\qquad h(0)=1\ .$$ We may assume that $h(z)\ne0$ in $U$. Since $U$ is simply connected the function $h$ has a well-defined square root $k:\ U\to{\mathbb C}$. We therefore have
$$\left({f(z)\over z}\right)^2=z\bigl(k(z)\bigr)^2\qquad (z\in\dot U)\ ,$$
or
$$z=\left({f(z)\over z\>k(z)}\right)^2=:\bigl(\phi(z)\bigr)^2\qquad (z\in\dot U)\ ,$$
where $\phi$ is analytic in $\dot U$.

But we all know that there is no analytic square root $\sqrt{z}$ in a full punctured disk around $0$.